# Automating NOAA reanalysis data download

Tags: api, noaa

Not sure if this question is on topic but I want to be able to automate the download of data from this site using a script- http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.ncep.reanalysis.pressure.html

Currently I can go here and manually download by clicking the variable that I want (such as surface pressure, time of day that I want the data , subset for the region and the pressure level(such as 500 hPa etc).

The same can be accomplished by harcoding the value of file that I want to download in a script.
I want to automate this process with some intelligence using a script. I want to pass as input the following

a) type of variable that i want to download such as surface pressure or temperature

b) time i.e data corresponds to which day

c) latitude /longitude of the subset that I want to download

d) pressure level( 500 hPa, 850 hPa etc).

These four variables will be sent each time for each HTTP download request.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the instructions to use the **NOAA** webservices API that provides access to current data - http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2 - according to their site:

> This API is for developers looking to create their own scripts or
>   programs that use the CDO database of weather and climate data. An
>   access token is required to use the API, and each token will be
>   limited to five requests per second and 1,000 requests per day.

Below is an illustration of the base url and end points.

[image: base url]

Comment: I went through that URL. I could not find a link to the reanalysis dataset.